# Are there any limitations in using Office Web Apps with SharePoint Foundation 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, office-web-apps, owa

We have the requirement of deploying Office Web Apps on SharePoint Foundation 2013.

So, I am just curious to know whether there are any limitation, drawbacks etc in using Office Web Apps with SharePoint Foundation 2013

Comment: I don't think so. But OWA users require MS Office 2013 license.

Comment: License is not a problem..is there any other limitation functionality wise..

Answer (score 4):

You need to deploy a separate server dedicated to Office Web Apps that does not have SharePoint installed on it.

In order to edit files in the browser, it requires a license that you can get through **Volume Licensing**. Getting the Office Web Apps installation now requires you to go through **Volume Licensing**, even though the product itself is free for read-only.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ac001a46-6ac9-4458-be7e-289a25055f7f/using-office-web-apps-server-with-sharepoint-foundation-2013?forum=sharepointgeneral

Answer (score 2):

Office Web Apps 2013 cannot be installed on the same servers as SharePoint 2013.  It needs to be on its own hardware (but can be virtualized).  If you are going to build with high availability in mind then you'll need more than one server and a load balancer.  In addition, if you are going to publish your SharePoint farm on the internet then you'll need to expose the Office Web App farm also.

Comment: any difference between configuring OWA with SharePoint Server 2013 and SharePoint Foundation 2013??

Comment: Not that I know of but I've only configured it on Server.  Based on the documentation I've seen it should be the same and it is done via PowerShell.

Comment: Please share the link of documentation if you have

Comment: Microsoft's Office Web Apps 2013 configuration documentation is here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431687.aspx